# SWI-Prolog: finding the second minimum in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the second minimum in the list that includes numbers and letters. When it includes a letter it should display an error and when it has one number then it should display an error. So far I have this but I'm not sure how to start off my code for having letters...

```
secondMin([_]) :- 
    print("ERROR: List has fewer than two unique elements."),
    !.
secondMin(List, M2) :- 
    min_list(List, M1), 
    delete(List, M1, List1), 
    min_list(List1, M2).
```

The output should look like this:

```
?- secondMin([17,29,11,62,37,53], M2).
M2 = 17
?- secondMin([512], M2).
ERROR: List has fewer than two unique elements.
?- secondMin([7,5.2,3,6,-3.6,9,-2], M2).
M2 = -2
?- secondMin([12,2,b,7], M2).
ERROR: "b" is not a number.
?- secondMin([3,3,3], M2).
ERROR: List has fewer than two unique elements.
```

Comment: What if it has elements that are neither an integer, nor a letter? For example, `abc`, or `1.23`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to say integer just any unique number

Comment: "Second minimum" sounds well defined. Yet, shall `secondMin([1,1,2,3],M)` now be `M = 1` or `M = 2`?

Comment: Is `abc` considered to be a *letter* then?

Comment: if abc was entered it would display an error saying abc is not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest, but imperative, approach is to use `maplist` to determine whether there are any non-numbers. Then use `sort` to get the unique, second min.

```
secondMin(L, M) :-
    (   maplist(number, L)
    ->  (   sort(L, [_,Second|_])
        ->  M = Second
        ;   print("List has fewer than two unique elements.")
        )
    ;   print("List has non-numeric elements")
    ).
```

---

As @repeat has pointed out in his comment, the above solution is "naive" in the sense that, although it produces a correct result for a valid input, it doesn't have appropriate error handling other than to display a diagnostic message but then succeed.

Here's a more thorough implementation which raises on exception when the first argument isn't defined as expected:

```
secondMin(L, M) :-
    (   ground(L)
    ->  (   is_list(L),
            maplist(number, L)
        ->  (   sort(L, [_,Second|_])
            ->  M = Second
            ;   throw('List has fewer than two unique elements')
            )
        ;   throw('First argument is not a list of numbers')
        )
    ;   throw(error(instantiation_error, _))
    ).
```

Comment: Your answer (which in erroneous cases prints out "ERROR" and *then succeeds*) is **way off**! Use exceptions instead! IIRC your main Prolog processor is GNU Prolog... so please read http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec32 and rephrase / improve your answer. I know using exceptions is a bit tiresome, but take the high road.

Comment: You might want to start with something like `( ground(L) -> ... ; throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) )` if you want to use `sort/2` in the code...

Comment: Another thing... the implicit unification in the `sort/2` goal should better be deferred to avoid issues with steadfastness. Why not do it like this: `( sort(L, [_,Second|_]) -> M = Second ; throw(...) )`

Comment: Thanks for adding `throw/1` goals! Now, how we get from something like `throw(up)` to something more serious? Let's ask @false for advise!

Comment: @repeat good points. I wasn't considering the steadfastness issues.